# Fetch current Url from android webkit browser

Tags: android, webkit

Is there a method to fetch the current url from the webkit browser of an android device. I dont want the Bookmarks or the Browsing history.. Only the current url..

Else is there a way to create a plug in for this browser so that each time the user enters the url, it is sent to my app instead of it browsing in the web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visiting the android docs I found for you this special link:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getUrl()

If this isn't what you wanted please specify again :)

Comment: the link goes to the webview but not the section I wanted it to go to.
try this:

String getUrl = WebView.getUrl();